# Algorithm for getting position value between 0 and 1

Tags: algorithm, polygon, vector-graphics

so i'm making some sort of 2d physics engine (yes, i know it's hard to make a physics engine from scratch) and i need help with a thing.

I need an algorithm that says where on the screen to draw the vertices of the polygon, it should give a number between 0 and 1, 0 being the smallest position possible (0) and 1 being the largest position possible (window width or height (1920 or 1080)).

I give every polygon these variables:

```
// = comment

x = [a number wetween 0 and 1]
y = [allso a number between 0 and 1]
width = [between 0 and 1]
height = [between 0 and 1]

vertices = [ // This makes a triangle
    0,   1, // bottom left of a "box" created at [x] * [window width], [y] * [window height] with the width of [width] * [window width] and height [height] * [window height]
    1,   1, // bottom right of the "box"
    0.5, 0 // top middle
]
```

How can i get where on the screen (in the 0-1 format) i should draw the vertices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, i got it now. It's `[x or y] + ([width or height] * [vertice])]`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to set the vertices relative to the bounds of the box and convert them to pixel coordinates. This can be done as follows:

`translate(x) = (vertex_x * box_width + box_x_start) * pixel_width`

`translate(y) = (vertex_y * box_height + box_y_start) * pixel_height`

Comment: No, i want to get where the individual vertices should be drawn :/

Comment: Yeah, so if `x = 0.5`, then the `x` pixel coordinate is `0.5 * 1920 = 960`. same with `y` coordinates.

Comment: Yeah, that gives me where the top left corner of the polygon "box" is, i want to get where the individual points/vertices of the polygon should be drawn

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I've updated my answer.